# Power BI Report Builder Multiple Parameter throwing error

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, reportbuilder

I have a Power BI Report Builder report that is throwing an error when I elect to have a multi-value parameter for month/year.  If I only select one month/year in the multi-value parameter the report processes fine.  However, if I select two month/year's in the multi-value parameter I receive the error below.

It seems to be an error in regards to a conversion of text to type date when processing. However, everything I have tried to fix this does not work.  Anyone have a fix?

Thank you greatly!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add more info, starting with your dataset query for the `FinancialReportPackageGrapple` dataset.

Comment: It looks like an issue when converting the multi-value in the query - though it should work. It seems to be converting the multiple dates into a single string ("Aug-2021, Sep-2021").How are you using the parameter? `IN (@PARMAM)`? What DB are you connecting to? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.  I actually just figured it out.  I added the parameter as a filter in the dataset properties and it now works.

Comment: Just a note - a parameter filters data on the server side - less work for SSRS whereas a dataset filter brings all the data back and throws away what is not needed. Sure, it works.. at what cost?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.